# Bitly API success shorten a URL but the long URL is wrong

Tags: php, api

I try to shorten a URL and use this code to shorten a URL, it's work to shorten but the long URL is wrong

```
<?php


/* make a URL small */
function make_bitly_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format = 'xml',$version = '2.0.1')
{
    //create the URL
    $bitly = 'http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version='.$version.'&longUrl='.urlencode($url).'&login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&format='.$format;

    //get the url
    //could also use cURL here
    $response = file_get_contents($bitly);

    //parse depending on desired format
    if(strtolower($format) == 'json')
    {
        $json = @json_decode($response,true);
        return $json['results'][$url]['shortUrl'];
    }
    else //xml
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        return 'http://bit.ly/'.$xml->results->nodeKeyVal->hash;
    }
}

?>
```

to call, i use this code:

```
<?php /* usage */
$short = make_bitly_url('http://test.com./sub/<?php echo $idplus;?>','user','API Key','json');
echo 'Bitly :  '.$short; 
?>
```

$idplus is the unique value that i got when entering url. When i use this code, the url can be shorted but the long URL will be `http://test.com/sub/<?php echo $idplus;?>` not `http://test.com/sub/idplus`, please help me to fix this problem because i do not know anything about coding :(

For make clear this case, when I visit a page like `test.com/test/123` i want to make a short URL with this long URL `abc.com/com/123`

Answer (score 0):

For call use this:

```
<?php /* usage */
$url = 'http://test.com./sub/' . $idplus;
$short = make_bitly_url($url,'user','API Key','json');
echo 'Bitly :  '.$short; 
?>
```